# Get later of two dates without using an if else

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, momentjs, fullcalendar-3

Using Moment.js how can I get the later of two dates without using an if else statement?  Is that possible?  I want the later of the two dates to assign to the start of the eventConstraint.

```
eventConstraint: {
    start: firstAvailableDate,
    end: moment().add('months', 1).endOf('month')
}
```

Can this be simplified?

```
var firstAvailablePatchDate = moment('2018-05-13T00:00:00');

var firstAvailableDate;

if (moment() > endPatchValidation) {
    firstAvailableDate = moment().add('days', 1);
}
else
{
    firstAvailableDate = firstAvailablePatchDate;
}
```

Comment: You could always use a ternary statement, which is technically an if, but a one liner.  Why do you not want an if?  You could also try `Math.max(moment(), endPatchValidation)` or whatever two values you want

Comment: @Taplar `moment(Math.max(moment(), endPatchValidation))` so the return is converted back to a moment object. That said, i'd stick with the moment functions personally.

Comment: @Taplar also, that doesnt actually solve the problem at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The requirement to "not use an if else statement" seems a bit arbitrary. That said, you should use moment's [`isBefore`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-before/) check and a ternary statement for this:

```
var firstAvailablePatchDate = moment('2018-05-13T00:00:00'); 
var firstAvailableDate = endPatchValidation.isBefore(moment()) ?  moment().add('days', 1) : firstAvailablePatchDate;
```

Comment: Cool.  The isBefore works for what I am trying to do.  Just need the correct variable on the end, firstAvailablePatchDate.    Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

you can with a ternary operation

```
moment() > endPatchValidation ? firstAvailableDate = moment().add('days', 1) : firstAvailableDate = firstAvailablePatchDate;
```